# Referencing a other object from QML function (QT 5.5)

Tags: qt, qml

the following works in QT 5.15:

```
Text {
    id: invisibleText;
    text: mainText.text
    
    property bool fitWithinParent : true /* simplified, most likely irelevant */
    
    property var referenceObject: (fitWithinParent)? parent : page /* page is a top level Window */
    property int baseFontSize : (referenceObject.height / 10) * 7
    font.family: currentFontName
    font.pointSize: baseFontSize
    color: "transparent"
}

Text {
    objectName: "numberText"
    id: mainText                                        
    text: ""
                            
    font.family: currentFontName

    function getFontSize() {
        let referenceObject = invisibleText.referenceObject; // Expected token ;
        let baseFontSize = invisibleText.baseFontSize;  // Expected token ;
        let fitFontSize = Math.min(baseFontSize, baseFontSize * ((invisibleText.paintedWidth > referenceObject.width)? (referenceObject.width / invisibleText.paintedWidth) : 1));  // Expected token ;

        if (mainText.text.slice(-1) == "A") {
            fitFontSize *= 0.94;
        }

        return fitFontSize * page.songNumberScaling;
    }

    font.pointSize: getFontSize();

    color: page.foregroundColor
}
```

In 5.5 when I try to run the project, it complains about missing `;` in the first three lines of the `getFontSize()` function.

Now since there is a ; and it shouldn't be required in JS anyway, I assume the problem is it cannot find the `invisibleText` reference, which is a sibling object. Any ideas?

Note that I need to get it running on QT 5.5 because the target device uses 5.5 and it's for many reasons impossible to upgrade it...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer JavaScript keywords, such as `let` wasn't introduced until Qt5.12+. So, if you're on Qt5.5, then, you'll need to use `var` instead.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47735